# How to fix error while using LookupIn in couchbase document error: "could not execute one or more multi lookups or mutations"

Tags: couchbase

I am executing the below code in my code flow and getting an error "`could not execute one or more multi lookups or mutations`". Please suggest if I am doing something wrong here.

I am using go SDK.

```
frag, err := bucket.LookupIn(id).Get("key").Execute()
if err != nil {
   log.Error("error:", err)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the property "key" is missed in that document. Looks error message is misleading from actual cause of issue.

It should be like "path not found".

Comment: This covered briefly in https://docs.couchbase.com/go-sdk/1.6/subdocument-operations.html#error-handling - you don't get the path not found as the top level error. As subdoc operates on multiple paths each individual path can return successfully or with an error.